# ActiveAdmin and has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

There are 2 models Customer and Order. Customer has_many orders. Is it possible to make orders appear as member for Customer. Url example:

localhost:3000/admin/customers/1/orders

This url would show orders model index page filtered by customer 1.

This could be achieved by using custom actions, but I need "Batch Actions" feature in orders index page. table_for is not creating "Batch Actions" button.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, nested routes.

routes.rb

```
resources :customers do
  resources :orders
end
```

customer.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

orders_controller.rb

```
def index
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:customer_id])
  @orders = @customer.orders.all
end
```

Where the route (without any admin namespacing) would be something like `customer_orders_path(customer)`.

I haven't used ActiveAdmin before, so maybe you'll have a bit of scoping on your routes.rb by default from that gem.